# How to Mock BlobContainerClient() of Azure.Storage.Blobs?

Tags: c#, azure, mocking, azure-blob-storage

I need some example of creating Mock object for BlobContainerClient of Azure.Storage.Blobs for unit testing. How can I create Mock for following class?

```
 public sealed class BlobStorageProcessor
    {
        public BlobStorageProcessor(ILogger logger, BlobContainerClient containerClient)
        {
            this.logger = logger;
            this.containerClient = containerClient;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Microsoft have now covered this in a blog post: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/azure-sdk/unit-testing-and-mocking/

Basically, you use the [`Moq`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Moq/) package to create a mock object and setup methods/properties that will be used by `BlobStorageProcessor`.

```cs
public static BlobContainerClient GetBlobContainerClientMock()
{
    var mock = new Mock<BlobContainerClient>();

    mock
        .Setup(i => i.AccountName)
        .Returns("Test account name");

    return mock.Object;
}
```

In your unit test you should inject result of `GetBlobContainerClientMock` method to `BlobStorageProcessor`:

```cs
var blobStorageProcessor = new BlobStorageProcessor(
    GetLoggerMock(),
    GetBlobContainerClientMock()
);
```

`GetLoggerMock` could by implemented similarly to `GetBlobContainerClientMock`. Read more info here: [Moq Quickstart](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart)

Comment: The problem I have with the Microsoft blog post you linked is that it is all about working with C# and makes no mention of what to do when working Java...

Comment: @cptully with all due respect, this isn't a problem of the answer or the blog post. The question is specifically targeting C# and not Java.

Comment: @cptully https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/issues/5017 There are different ways you can accomplish that in Java, listed in the github issue above. One is this way from Mockito docs: https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/What's-new-in-Mockito-2#unmockable